# I cannot find shared items in Windows 10

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have an issue when sharing items in Windows 10.

When I share a file or folder by right-click > give access to > Specific people and I choose Everyone, I can see the Users folder in the list of shares, but not the individual file or folder I shared.

Example:

I want to share this folder: `C:\Users\User1\Documents\TTEEE2\SHARE 2`.

I share it by right-click > give access to > Specific people.

Then I want to check the items I shared: such as by entering Net Share in the Command Line Interface.

The result is that it shows this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net share

Share name Resource Remark

…I omitted the $ shares…

Users C:\Users

The command completed successfully.
```

The issue is that, instead of showing the folder I shared, it shows `C:\Users…`

How can I see what I really shared? i.e.: the “SHARE 2” folder

This doesn’t happen when I share with Advanced Sharing.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: When giving access to Specific people, which account/people did you specify? Was it Everyone?

Comment: Yes, I set it for Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give the Everyone permission to a sub-folder of the
`C:\Users` folder, which is heavily protected by Windows.
You will need to modify the permissions on
`C:\Users\User1\Documents\TTEEE2\SHARE 2` and all its parents
to enable this, and this might or might not work in the end,
or might or might not keep working after the next Windows upgrade.

It will be much easier to share a folder or sub-folder that is outside
of any special and protected Windows folder.

You could perhaps move your documents elsewhere. See for example
[How to move Documents folder to another drive in windows 10/11](https://thegeekpage.com/move-documents-folder-to-another-drive/).